# pytorch backprop through volatile variable error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm trying to minimize some input relative to some target by running it through several backward pass iterations and updating the input at each step. The first pass runs successfully but I get the following error on the second pass:

`RuntimeError: element 0 of variables tuple is volatile`

This code snippet demonstrates the problem

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn

inp = Variable(torch.Tensor([1]), requires_grad=True)
target = Variable(torch.Tensor([3]))

loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

for i in range(2):
    loss = loss_fn(inp, target)
    loss.backward()
    gradient = inp.grad
    inp = inp - inp.grad * 0.01
```

When I inspect the value of `inp`, before it is reassigned on the last line, `inp.volatile => False` and `inp.requires_grad => True` but after it is reassigned those switch to `True` and `False`, respectively. Why does being a volatile variable prevent the second backprop run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must zero out the gradient before each update like this:

```
inp.grad.data.zero_()
```

But in your code every time you update the gradient you are creating another `Variable` object, so you must update entire history like this:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn

inp_hist = []
inp = Variable(torch.Tensor([1]), requires_grad=True)
target = Variable(torch.Tensor([3]))

loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

for i in range(2):
    loss = loss_fn(inp, target)
    loss.backward()
    gradient = inp.grad
    inp_hist.append(inp)
    inp = inp - inp.grad * 0.01
    for inp in inp_hist:
        inp.grad.data.zero_()
```

But this way you will compute the gradient for all previous inputs you have created in the history(and it's bad, it's a wast of everything), a correct implementation looks like this:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
inp = Variable(torch.Tensor([1]), requires_grad=True)
target = Variable(torch.Tensor([3]))
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
for i in range(2):
    loss = loss_fn(inp, target)
    loss.backward()
    gradient = inp.grad
    inp.data = inp.data - inp.grad.data * 0.01
    inp.grad.data.zero_()
```

Comment: In your second to last line do you mean `inp.data = ...` instead of `inp.grad.data`? So this is essentially an in place modification of the same `Variable` whereas the previous example creates new `Variable`'s each time? In the first example, if i create a new `Variable` each iteration, why would the gradients from previous variables be updated?

Comment: Thank you :) that was a mistake :D