# PyTorch: RuntimeError: element 0 of variables tuple is volatile

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient, pytorch

I'm training a LSTM based model in PyTorch 0.3.1.

My problem is that after increasing the learning rate I always get a `RuntimeError` saying: `element 0 of variables tuple is volatile`.

This does not happen at the beginning, but after some training, like in epoch 3, 4, 5 .. etc.

When looking after this error I found [this Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513276/pytorch-backprop-through-volatile-variable-error) suggesting to use `zero_grad()`. But this was already in use when the error occurred.

So my questions are:

- What does it mean that an element of a variable is volatile?
- And what are possible causes for a variables element to get "volatile"?
- Is there a way to test which variable contains the volatile element, so that I can backtrace the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Here is the code of the training step I'm using:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    states = (Var(torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)), 
              Var(torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)))
    new_batch = True
    step = 0
    epoch_loss = []
    print('Epoch: ', epoch+1)
    for i in range(0, token_ids.size(1) - seq_length, seq_length):
        #print(i)
        input_sequence = Var(token_ids[:,i:i+seq_length])
        target_sequence = Var(token_ids[:,(i+1):(i+1)+seq_length])
        entity_target_sequence = Var(entety_targets[:,(i+1):(i+1)+seq_length]).contiguous()

        if int(input_sequence )== 0:
            states = (Var(torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)), 
                      Var(torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)))
            print('New Document')
        model.zero_grad()
        states = detach(states)
        out, states, z = model(input_sequence, states)

        if new_batch:
            loss = loss_func(out, target_sequence.view(-1)) + bce_loss(z, entity_target_sequence)
            new_batch = False
        else:
            loss += loss_func(out, target_sequence.view(-1)) + bce_loss(z, entity_target_sequence)
        if (i+1) % wbatch_size == 0:
            step += 1 // seq_length
            if step % 10 == 0:
                epoch_loss.append((loss.data[0]/wbatch_size))
                print ('Epoch [%d/%d], Step[%d/%d], Loss: %.3f' % (epoch+1, num_epochs, step, num_wbatches, (loss.data[0]/wbatch_size)))
                sys.stdout.flush()

            loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(model.parameters(), 0.5)
            optimizer.step()
            new_batch = True
```

(I left out the model itself to avoid a wall of code here and to keep this readable, but if this helps to solve the problem I can of course add the code.)

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ent_lm.py", line 223, in <module>
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py", line 167, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, retain_variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 99, in backward
    variables, grad_variables, retain_graph)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems ok.

The error would appear to happen during one of the following two functions.

```
states = detach(states)
out, states, z = model(input_sequence, states)
```

I think part of the reason might be that your require "retain graph" but you keep resetting the graph when you detach the states or do something else in your model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Is there any way to track this back? Meaning any way to test which of the variables causes this at what position.
Do you have any resource where I can read about what it actually means that an element of the variable tuple is volatile?

Comment: You can read more about volatile here: http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=volatile#torch.autograd.backward  I would test it out by first removing retain_graph=True as you're not using the model twice so you don't need to keep around old gradients and go from there.